# Troubleshooting outdoor electrical outlet

Tags: electrical, receptacle, outdoor, electrical-panel

I bought a new house and noticed the outdoor electrical outlets are not working. I checked the electrical panel and all the switches are on (the outdoor outlets are labelled on the panel and I turned them off, then on without success). The outdoor lights are working. None of my two outdoor electrical outlets has a reset button (is this normal?).

I don't have much knowledge in electricity, is there anything else I can check before calling an electrician?

Comment: trace the wires to where they come out of the house and see if they are disconnected somewhere, also they may be GFCI protection on them that you may need to reset.

Comment: You might want to look around the house, for example near the switches for the outdoor lights, for a blank face GFCI which has only the test and reset buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to call an electrician after trying what has been proposed in the thread (thanks to all). It turned out to be an error with how the wires were installed in the electrical panel. Took just a few minutes to repair.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no GFCI on the outside outlet it likely is chained off of a GFCI outlet inside.  The first thing to look for would be any other outlets inside, probably but not necessarily near where the outside wire enters the building.

There may instead be just a GFCI (without the outlets) somewhere inside.